# Jquery animation not working properlty

Tags: jquery

I am trying to minimize and expand a div on a 'click' event using **jquery** animate() function. But When the height of div reduced to 0px, the contents inside the div still visible. I need the content inside the div should be hidden when the div height become 0px and visible when div expands. Please help me. work it out

html code

```
<ul>
<div class="box">
    <li>Input One</li>
    <div class="content">
        <input type="text" id="input1" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <li>Input Two</li>
    <div class="content">
        <input type="text" id="input2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Css code

```
li {
list-style:none;
background-color:#666;
width:200px;
color:#f0f0f0;
cursor:pointer;
}
.box {
width:200px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.content {
background-color:#ddd;
}
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("li").on('click', function () {
    var par = $(this).parent('.box');

    if (par.children('.content').css("height") !== "0px") {

        par.children('.content').animate({
            "height": "0px",
            "min-height": "0px"
        });
    } else {

        par.children('.content').animate({
            "min-height": "20px",
            "height": "auto"
        });
    }
});

});
```

Check out this code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLMbd/)

Comment: Why not use slideToggle()?

Comment: you can use overflow:hidden; on the .content

Comment: @isherwood :) I tried slideToggle() now, its working fine. But Why its not working using animate()?. Is this a drawback of animate() function?

Comment: Animate doesn't automatically handle overflow, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked for, but much more elegant, I'd say:

```
$("li").on('click', function () {
    $(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/BLMbd/4/

By the way, your HTML is invalid. The only siblings allowed for LIs are LIs.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to know why are you writing all those lines of code when you've got `slideToggle()`.

```
$('li').click(function () {
  $('.content').slideToggel();
});
```

I have provided the code for one `li`, you can try to use `this` to make sure the `.content` that has to slide is from the current one, and the other one is still in its position!

Also note the issue that you were falling into, was from the `height`.

You can try to use some `background-color`, just to check how the height is changed for that div. But the content is still there!